# Remove duplicates by prioritising a categorical value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.3

My database has some entries for which a categorical field has been updated and the old value wasn't removed. I want to keep only the entry with the "highest" categorical value, in an order which I define.

Input:

```
id | degree
=============
1  | Diploma
1  | Bachelors
1  | Masters
2  | Diploma
2  | Bachelors
```

Output (desired):

```
id | degree
=============
1  | Masters
2  | Bachelors
```

I tried using CASE with the "highest" value last in an attempt to overwrite the previous values, but it does not work as intended.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    (CASE
        WHEN id = 'Diploma'   THEN 'Diploma'
        WHEN id = 'Bachelors' THEN 'Bachelors'
        WHEN id = 'Masters'   THEN 'Masters'
    END) as degree
FROM
    academic_record
```

Is there a method for this operation?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Am I right to assume that you meant that  Masters > Bachelors > Diploma?

Comment: That's correct. The logic is that I wish to check each case in turn, and if the case is true, then set the value. The next case may overwrite the value. (This may not be optimal, but is sufficient. A better method may simply check all cases before setting the value, without the need to overwrite "superseded" values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `case` for ordering is the right idea. I'd query the `rank` over it for each id, and then take the top ones:

```
SELECT id, degree
FROM   (SELECT id,
               degree,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                            ORDER BY CASE degree WHEN 'Diploma'   THEN 1
                                                 WHEN 'Bachelors' THEN 2
                                                 WHEN 'Masters'   THEN 3
                                     END DESC) AS rn
        FROM   academic_record) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you.